# For Linq Select Statement, how to construct a SubClass in a general way at run time?

Tags: c#, linq, select, runtime, subclass

The fake code is:

```
  public class ParentClass
      { decimal quantity, 
        decimal price
      }

  IQueryable<ParentClass> parents;

  //SonClass is created at run time 
  //SonClass has some extra property, such as amount=quantity*price, which is defined by a string at run time

  IQueryable<SonClass> sons=parents.Select(p=>new SonClass(p){ attachedProperty1=..., attachedProperty2=...})
```

If I have the source code of ParentClass, I know how to create the sonClass at run time. Actually SonClass should have a suitable constructor for the Linq select statement. 
   I tried the following fake code:

```
    public SonClass(ParentClass parent)
{
... 
}
```

When we don't have the source code of ParentClass, how to write a generic code ?

Or, maybe you have a new way to get the same result. The desired results is to create a subclass of ParentClass dynamically with extra read only properties defined by Linq Select statement.

Thank you in advance.

Ying

Comment: There is an example to show user defined type can be used in LINQ Select statement. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/swiss_dpe_team/archive/2008/01/25/using-your-own-defined-type-in-a-linq-query-expression.aspx .

Comment: if this is a dynamic class (so the properties aren't known until runtime), what is the consumer going to do with it?  you could use IDynamicObject I guess - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245975/how-do-you-implement-c4s-idynamicobject-interface

Comment: 1. Although it is a dynamic class, it is a subclass of the original class. So the consumer will treat it as the original one.

2. It seems IDynamicObject is not I am looking for.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is (currently) possible. From the C# Programmers Guide at MSDN, regarding  [anonymous types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696(VS.90).aspx):

> Anonymous types are reference types
>   that derive directly from object. The
>   compiler gives them a name although
>   your application cannot access it.
>   From the perspective of the common
>   language runtime, an anonymous type is
>   no different from any other reference
>   type, except that it cannot be cast to
>   any type except for object.

Answer (score 0):

you need not construct any sub class, an anonymous class is generated for you at runtime

```
var sons=parents.Select(p=>new { attachedProperty1=p..., attachedProperty2=p...})
foreach (var son in sons){
     Console.WriteLine(son.PropertyName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to create a dynamic type that extends an existing type and injects custom properties. I'm pretty sure that's impossible in a single LINQ statement (you'd need either C#4.0 dynamics or some reflection madness).

However, you can create anonymous classes with any properties you like:

```
var sons = parents.Select(p =>new { parentProperty1=p.Prop1, attachedProperty1=..., tachedProperty2=...});
```

Or:

```
var sons = parents.Select(p =>new { parent=p, attachedProperty1=..., tachedProperty2=...});
```

Alternatively, why don't you have an "additional properties" (type object or Dictionary) property on your ParentClass so you could do this:

```
var sons = parents.ForEach(p => p.AdditionalProps = new { attachedProperty1=..., tachedProperty2=...});
```

You *could* write an extension method that used reflection to grab all the public properties of a given object, merge them with a given anonymous object (your "attachedProperty1 etc. object") and return a new anonymous object with all merged properties. However, this would be a poor solution - a better solution would probably be to return a Dictionary<string, object> instead of an anonymous type because even if you did create a merged anonymous type you wouldn't be able to access its properties in a type-safe manner.